# Does it exists in visual studio 2008 custom templates as in Eclipse?

Tags: visual-studio, templates

I'm adding logging to a visual studio 2008 application, c#, windows form. I'm using log4net, and I was wondering if there is in Visual Studio, any feature similar to custom templates in Eclipse.

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks,

Fernando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure [visual studio templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Andrei-Shcneider, but what i mean by Eclispe custom templates is different. Eclipse templates allows you to insert pieces of code, based on a custom template, and avoid to write repetitive code. Here you can see this link: http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ

Comment: In Visual studio you can use code snippets, but they are not very powerful. It's better to use the Resharper extension. It has a nice feature called live templates. http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_templates.html

Comment: Yes, I was looking to code snippets, but there are things that you cannot do, like put a method name, or the list of input arguments. I'll go for resharper. Thanks again!